# Choose groups by category of person

Tags: combinatorics

Sorry for the vague title, I'm not really sure what the correct terminology for this type of questions is.

I have to hire 6 people: 2 programmers, 2 footballers and 2 logicians. I receive 90 applications for the positions. The number of people applying for each position is

- 25 footballers
- 25 programmers
- 20 logicians
- 10 footballers who are also logicians
- 9 programmers who are also footballers
- 1 logician who is also a programmer

How many ways can I choose 6 applicants, given that some applicants are suitable for 2 positions?

So the number of applications for the footballer position is 44 (25 + 10 + 9). Therefore, if we ignore the other positions, the combinations of footballers I can choose is 946 (44 choose 2).

However this ignores the other positions which may take away the footballers who are also programmers/logicians. Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this?

Thanks
JP

Comment: Have you learned about the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)? It seems like it might apply, but if you haven't covered it, it's unlikely that you're expected to use it.

Comment: pjs36 - I do remember that from a long time ago, but unfortunately this isn't a homework problem but an actual programming problem I'm trying to solve! I will read up on that and find out more - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$, $p$, $l$, $fp$, $fl$, $lp$ denote the numbers of pure footballers, pure programmers, pure logicians, footballer-programmers, footballer-logicians and logician-programmers.

Given any selection $S$ of persons with the specified frequencies $f,p,l,fp,fl,lp$, let $\Gamma=\Gamma(f,p,l,fp,fl,lp)$ denote the number of distinct ways of assigning them to the available positions.  We see that $\Gamma$ is equal to $\frac{1}{8}$ times the number of "compatible" bijections from $S$ to the multiset $\{f,f,p,p,l,l\}$.  (Here, compatible means that jobs only go to qualified persons.  The factor of $\frac{1}{8}$ comes from the symmetries of the multiset.)

Then the total number of possibilities is: $$
\sum_{f \geq 0}
\sum_{p \geq 0}
\sum_{l \geq 0}
\sum_{fp \geq 0}
\sum_{fl \geq 0}
\sum_{lp \geq 0}
\Gamma
\binom{25}{f}
\binom{25}{l}
\binom{20}{p}
\binom{9}{fp}
\binom{10}{fl}
\binom{1}{lp}.
$$

Now, many $6$-tuples $(f,p,l,fp,fl,lp)$ make a zero contribution to the sum.  There are 114 $6$-tuples that result in a non-zero contribution, as listed below, along with the product of the six binomials.

```
1   f f fl fl fp fp  Gamma=1 Factor=486000
2   f f fl fl fp p  Gamma=1 Factor=2430000
3   f f fl fl fp pl  Gamma=1 Factor=121500
4   f f fl fl p p  Gamma=1 Factor=2565000
5   f f fl fl p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=270000
6   f f fl fp fp l  Gamma=1 Factor=2700000
7   f f fl fp fp pl  Gamma=1 Factor=108000
8   f f fl fp l p  Gamma=1 Factor=13500000
9   f f fl fp l pl  Gamma=1 Factor=675000
10  f f fl fp p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=540000
11  f f fl l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=14250000
12  f f fl l p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=1500000
13  f f fl p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=570000
14  f f fp fp l l  Gamma=1 Factor=3240000
15  f f fp fp l pl  Gamma=1 Factor=270000
16  f f fp l l p  Gamma=1 Factor=16200000
17  f f fp l l pl  Gamma=1 Factor=810000
18  f f fp l p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=1350000
19  f f l l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=17100000
20  f f l l p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=1800000
21  f f l p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=1425000
22  f fl fl fl fp fp  Gamma=3 Factor=108000
23  f fl fl fl fp p  Gamma=3 Factor=540000
24  f fl fl fl fp pl  Gamma=3 Factor=27000
25  f fl fl fl p p  Gamma=3 Factor=570000
26  f fl fl fl p pl  Gamma=3 Factor=60000
27  f fl fl fp fp fp  Gamma=3 Factor=94500
28  f fl fl fp fp l  Gamma=2 Factor=1012500
29  f fl fl fp fp p  Gamma=2 Factor=810000
30  f fl fl fp fp pl  Gamma=4 Factor=40500
31  f fl fl fp l p  Gamma=2 Factor=5062500
32  f fl fl fp l pl  Gamma=2 Factor=253125
33  f fl fl fp p p  Gamma=1 Factor=1923750
34  f fl fl fp p pl  Gamma=3 Factor=202500
35  f fl fl l p p  Gamma=2 Factor=5343750
36  f fl fl l p pl  Gamma=2 Factor=562500
37  f fl fl p p pl  Gamma=2 Factor=213750
38  f fl fp fp fp l  Gamma=3 Factor=525000
39  f fl fp fp fp pl  Gamma=3 Factor=21000
40  f fl fp fp l l  Gamma=1 Factor=2700000
41  f fl fp fp l p  Gamma=2 Factor=4500000
42  f fl fp fp l pl  Gamma=3 Factor=225000
43  f fl fp fp p pl  Gamma=2 Factor=180000
44  f fl fp l l p  Gamma=1 Factor=13500000
45  f fl fp l l pl  Gamma=1 Factor=675000
46  f fl fp l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=10687500
47  f fl fp l p pl  Gamma=2 Factor=1125000
48  f fl fp p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=427500
49  f fl l l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=14250000
50  f fl l l p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=1500000
51  f fl l p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=1187500
52  f fp fp fp l l  Gamma=3 Factor=630000
53  f fp fp fp l pl  Gamma=3 Factor=52500
54  f fp fp l l p  Gamma=2 Factor=5400000
55  f fp fp l l pl  Gamma=2 Factor=270000
56  f fp fp l p pl  Gamma=2 Factor=450000
57  f fp l l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=12825000
58  f fp l l p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=1350000
59  f fp l p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=1068750
60  fl fl fl fl fp fp  Gamma=6 Factor=7560
61  fl fl fl fl fp p  Gamma=6 Factor=37800
62  fl fl fl fl fp pl  Gamma=6 Factor=1890
63  fl fl fl fl p p  Gamma=6 Factor=39900
64  fl fl fl fl p pl  Gamma=6 Factor=4200
65  fl fl fl fp fp fp  Gamma=9 Factor=10080
66  fl fl fl fp fp l  Gamma=3 Factor=108000
67  fl fl fl fp fp p  Gamma=6 Factor=86400
68  fl fl fl fp fp pl  Gamma=9 Factor=4320
69  fl fl fl fp l p  Gamma=3 Factor=540000
70  fl fl fl fp l pl  Gamma=3 Factor=27000
71  fl fl fl fp p p  Gamma=3 Factor=205200
72  fl fl fl fp p pl  Gamma=6 Factor=21600
73  fl fl fl l p p  Gamma=3 Factor=570000
74  fl fl fl l p pl  Gamma=3 Factor=60000
75  fl fl fl p p pl  Gamma=3 Factor=22800
76  fl fl fp fp fp fp  Gamma=6 Factor=5670
77  fl fl fp fp fp l  Gamma=6 Factor=94500
78  fl fl fp fp fp p  Gamma=3 Factor=75600
79  fl fl fp fp fp pl  Gamma=9 Factor=3780
80  fl fl fp fp l l  Gamma=1 Factor=486000
81  fl fl fp fp l p  Gamma=4 Factor=810000
82  fl fl fp fp l pl  Gamma=5 Factor=40500
83  fl fl fp fp p p  Gamma=1 Factor=307800
84  fl fl fp fp p pl  Gamma=5 Factor=32400
85  fl fl fp l l p  Gamma=1 Factor=2430000
86  fl fl fp l l pl  Gamma=1 Factor=121500
87  fl fl fp l p p  Gamma=2 Factor=1923750
88  fl fl fp l p pl  Gamma=3 Factor=202500
89  fl fl fp p p pl  Gamma=2 Factor=76950
90  fl fl l l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=2565000
91  fl fl l l p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=270000
92  fl fl l p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=213750
93  fl fp fp fp fp l  Gamma=6 Factor=31500
94  fl fp fp fp fp pl  Gamma=6 Factor=1260
95  fl fp fp fp l l  Gamma=3 Factor=252000
96  fl fp fp fp l p  Gamma=3 Factor=420000
97  fl fp fp fp l pl  Gamma=6 Factor=21000
98  fl fp fp fp p pl  Gamma=3 Factor=16800
99  fl fp fp l l p  Gamma=2 Factor=2160000
100 fl fp fp l l pl  Gamma=2 Factor=108000
101 fl fp fp l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=1710000
102 fl fp fp l p pl  Gamma=3 Factor=180000
103 fl fp fp p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=68400
104 fl fp l l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=5130000
105 fl fp l l p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=540000
106 fl fp l p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=427500
107 fp fp fp fp l l  Gamma=6 Factor=37800
108 fp fp fp fp l pl  Gamma=6 Factor=3150
109 fp fp fp l l p  Gamma=3 Factor=504000
110 fp fp fp l l pl  Gamma=3 Factor=25200
111 fp fp fp l p pl  Gamma=3 Factor=42000
112 fp fp l l p p  Gamma=1 Factor=2052000
113 fp fp l l p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=216000
114 fp fp l p p pl  Gamma=1 Factor=171000
```

If we sum this all up, we obtain `244833400` possibilities.

(This was computed using the computer algebra system [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/).)

Comment: (Hopefully the program using e.g. `fl fl` to mean two footballer-logicians is not too confusing; even though it clashes with my earlier notation.)

Comment: the programming is fine! Thanks very much. Out of interest do you know of a package in R that would do this kind of calculation?

Comment: Can you please add some further explanation about the gamma value? I'm sorry but "compatible bijections" is a bit beyond my maths comprehension!

Comment: Suppose persons A, B, C, D, E, F were chosen, and A, B, C, D were all footballer-programmers and E, F were logicians.  Then we could choose {A,B} as the footballers and {C,D} as the programmers.  Alternatively, we could choose {A,C} as the footballers and {B,D} as the programmers, and so on.  Gamma counts the permissible possibilities (the given example is number 107 on the list, and there's 6 distinct ways).

Comment: That makes it a lot clearer, thank you. I still do not see how it is calculated (or where the 1/8 comes into it) but I think I can just find gamma with a recursive loop for each case. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that the "naive" way to choose the 2 footballers would be $\begin{pmatrix} 44 \\ 2\end{pmatrix}$. Likewise, there are $\begin{pmatrix} 35\\2 \end{pmatrix}$ naive ways to choose the 2 programmers, and $\begin{pmatrix} 31\\2 \end{pmatrix}$ naive ways to choose the logicians, so that their product is the answer of "naive" ways to choose the six hires.

It's naive because we've certainly (as you point out) double counted some of our people, possibly hiring someone as both a footballer and logician for example. So, we've overcounted by some currently unknown number and have to revise our "naive" approach.

What scenarios have been overcounted? Hiring someone as a footballer and logician, for one. Second, hiring someone as both a footballer and programmer. Finally, we could double hire the programmer logician.

We might subtract off each of these counts from our naive answer, but does that take care of it? I think not; I think there are many many "bad" scenarios that this doesn't take care of.

We can "double hire" 0,1, or 2 footballers. Likewise with programmers, but we can only "double hire" 0 or 1 logicians. Thus, I think there are $3\cdot 3 \cdot 2 - 1$ cases that we need to subtract off: double hiring only a footballer; only 2 footballers; a programmer; 2 programmers; the logician; a single footballer and a single programmer; and so on.

This sounds really computationally horrendous. I hope there's a simpler solution and someone else chimes in!